# Link to Page Anchor pad top

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a sticky navigation on the top of my page and i also have one as the right column.

My problem is that when i link the side navigation to an anchor it scrolls the page to that anchor and puts it behind the top navigation.

Is there anyway that i can have it so it scrolls the page to `100px` above the actual anchor so it isn't behind the top sticky navigation?

I am using bootstrap with `affix-top` on the top navigation and `data-spy="scroll" and also`affix` on the right column navigation

**bold**

Since i am using the `data-spy="scroll"` this affects the way that the `scrollspy` works since the anchor goes behind the top navigation before it changes the spy on the side navigation.

This is why i ant to have an offset on my anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can set this up so that it won't interfere with the rest of your layout, the following is an easy manner to do what you want:

**Sample Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qWHgR/**

```
selector {
    padding-top: 200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

I'm not personally familiar with Scrollspy so you may have to make some minor changes to it if the offset becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @Nit suggestion. I like that it works beautifully well on inline and block level elements, wouldn't have thought.

http://jsfiddle.net/gCs7C/

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#hash">Scroll to content</a>
</nav>
<div>Spacer</div>
<div>
    Spacer<br />
    <span id="hash">Content</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

div {
    height: 1000px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    height: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#hash {
    padding-top: 24px;
    margin-top: -24px;
}
```